# mvn -Dtest=MyTest fails to find MyTest after upgrading to surefire from 2.8.1 to 2.12

Tags: maven, surefire

anyone else seeing that?

`mvn test -Dtest=MyTest` //finds and runs MyTest with surefire 2.8.1, finds 0 matches with 2.12

> $mvn -version Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 09:31:09-0800)
>   Maven home: C:\mvn Java version: 1.7.0_01, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: C:\Java\jdk7\jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding:
>   Cp1252 OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family:
>   "windows"

Comment: looks like it's a bug:https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-824

Answer (score 1):

it's a bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-824

> **SpecificTestClassFilterTest currently fails on windows**
>   Type: Bug
>   Status: CLOSED
>   Priority: Major
>   Resolution: Fixed
>   Affects Version/s: 2.12
>   Fix Version/s: 2.12.3